# R: Removing zero rows from a matrix and keep the row indexes

Tags: r, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
one   0e+00 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00
two   1e-05 2e-05 3e-05 4e-05
three 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00
four  0e+00 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00
```

I want to remove all the zero rows and still leave it as a matrix, **not a data frame**, and keep the index **two** in this case, the output should be like this:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
two   1e-05 2e-05 3e-05 4e-05
```

Here is the code:

```
mat=matrix(c(0e+00,1e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,2e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,3e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,4e-05,0e+00,0e+00), nrow=4)
rownames(mat)= c("one", "two", "three", "four")
mat=mat[which(rowSums(mat) > 0),]
```

It removes all the zero rows, but instead of leaving the result as a matrix, it creates a list.

Comment: It doesn't create a `list`, it creates a `numeric vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrices of one row or column are by default turned into vectors by "dropping" the dimension attribute. You can stop this by adding the `drop = FALSE` argument to `[`.

```
mat=matrix(c(0e+00,1e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,2e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,3e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,4e-05,0e+00,0e+00), nrow=4)
rownames(mat) = c("one", "two", "three", "four")
mat = mat[which(rowSums(mat) > 0), , drop = FALSE]
mat
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# two 1e-05 2e-05 3e-05 4e-05
class(mat)
# [1] "matrix"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mat=matrix(c(0e+00,1e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,2e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,3e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,4e-05,0e+00,0e+00), nrow=4)
rownames(mat)= c("one", "two", "three", "four")
mat=mat[rowSums(mat==0) !=ncol(mat),]
mat
```

Comment: this creates again a list not a matrix and doesn't keep the index of the row